# Ошибка при создании таблицы с REFERENCES в Postgres-XL

Tags: sql, postgresql

При создании таблицы адресов все хорошо **DB: Postgres-XL**

```
CREATE TABLE addresses (
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  address text,
  label text,
  created_at timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
) DISTRIBUTE BY HASH(id)
```

При создании ссылочной таблицы address_ledger_entries с REFERENCES на таблицу addresses получаю ошибку - **Hash/Modulo distribution column does not refer to hash/modulo distribution column in referenced table.**

```
CREATE TABLE address_entries (
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  address_id bigint REFERENCES addresses,
  amount bigint NOT NULL
) DISTRIBUTE BY HASH(id)
```

**Уверен, что кто-то через такой опыт прошел и сможет с нами поделиться решением, как правильно использовать REFERENCES в Postgres-XL.**

Comment: Ну в документации написано "_PRIMARY KEY and foreign key must include the distribution column_". т.е. колонка которая ссылается то же должна быть distribute. Что в принципе логично, целостность можно проверить только в пределах ноды. А вот как этого добиться, можно ли написать там address_id в distribute, не знаю, никогда XL не видел

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что вторую таблицу надо дистрибутить не по id, а по address_id, что опять же логично, что бы join по этому ключу мог пройти в пределах ноды. но вот что будет когда появится третья таблица, ссылающаяся на address_entries не представляю

Comment: А если явно `address_id bigint REFERENCES addresses (id),`?

Comment: address_id bigint REFERENCES addresses (id) - ну конечно я пробовал и НЕТ )

Comment: Так вы попробовали во второй таблице сделать `DISTRIBUTE BY HASH(address_id)`, должно помочь ...

Comment: Да я пробовал `DISTRIBUTE BY HASH(address_id)` но всеравно проблема ERROR:  Unique index of partitioned table must contain the hash distribution column.

Comment: В документации https://www.postgres-xl.org/documentation/ddl-constraints.html (п. 5.3.5) явно сказано: "_Please note that column with REFERENCES should be the distribution column. In this case, we cannot add PRIMARY KEY to order_id because PRIMARY KEY must be the distribution column as well. This limitation is introduced because constraints are enforced only locally in each Datanode._". Т.е. distribute таблица при наличии внешних ключей не может иметь primary key.

Comment: И эта фраза подтверждает мое предположение, что все ссылающиеся друг на друга записи должны быть на одной ноде, что накладывает серьезные ограничения на то, как такие таблицы могут использоваться

Comment: Да верно, заработало но есть НО. ошибка появлялась из за того что я таблицу создавал еще с другими колонками как здесь в примере
`CREATE TABLE address_entries (
        address_id bigint REFERENCES addresses(id),
        transaction_id bigint REFERENCES transactions(id),
        input_id bigint REFERENCES inputs(id),
        output_id bigint REFERENCES outputs(id),
        amount bigint NOT NULL
      ) DISTRIBUTE BY HASH(address_id);`
как быть когда REFERENCES больше чем один, есть идеи?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73157/discussion-between-andrey-zhuk-and-mike).

Comment: Вот это боюсь не решаемо. Я понимаю почему у них такие ограничения. Им надо что бы каждая нода внутри себя могла проверить и уникальность и все ссылки. Кроме того мне сложно представить боле менее приемлемый по скорости запрос с join нескольких таблиц, если связанные этими join данные находятся на разных серверах. Если ссылка одна, то каждая нода выполняет join только своих данных, потом результаты нод объединяются и все. А если они разбросаны, то между всеми нодами фактически должны быть переданы все исходные таблицы для join. и это явно медленнее, чем выполнение всего на 1 сервере

Comment: В общем для соблюдения этого условия вам во все таблицы надо притащить некий общий ключ, по которому данные можно было бы разбросать по нодам так, что бы любые данные используемые в join связке в одном запросе (любом) оказались на одном сервере. Какие то мелкие справочники при этом можно было бы дублировать на всех серверах. В общем внимательно смотреть модель всей БД и искать общий знаменатель.

Comment: Привет Mike, у нас общий знаменатель это версия блока в блокчейне, все данные так или иначе связаны с конкретным блоком это адреса, входы, выходы, транзакции. По версии блока мы хотим дистрибутировать данные на разные сервера. Можешь подсказать примерный SQL. CREATE TABLE blocks...  addresses.. inputs.. outputs..transactions